# How do I get compositionupdate events on an HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to create a custom text entry widget inside a Canvas (this is a WebAssembly app that is using only a canvas, like Figma does), but there does not seem to be a way to get compositionupdate events, so it is not possible to enter non-ASCII characters. In fact, for Chinese text, the composition window does not even open up, despite the canvas having text focus, so I assume that the browser does not even try to do text handling. Figma obviously supports text entry, so how do they do it?

(In case it matters, I'm using Emscripten. Also, it would be helpful to get regular text events, too. I can get the key up/down events with no problem, but does not reliably translate into the conceptual character the user thinks they typed.)